# DHCP second scope has no internet access

Tags: windows, router, dhcp

I created 2 dchp scopes but the 2nd scope cannot access the internet. Someone told me I have to route the 2 scopes. My setup is ( isp~router[dlink]~server + switch[with 40host]). My problem im not fully aware of this routing the two dhcp? Should I config it at the router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "second DHCP scope" is ambiguous. You can setup multiple DHCP scopes on the same subnet, or you can create a scope each on two different subnets.

I'm assuming you created a second scope, on a different subnet.

So you have something like this for each scope:
192.168.10.1-100
192.168.20.1-100

Your Dlink router is probably sitting at something like 192.168.10.1.

Therefore, machines on 192.168.20.x cannot communicate with the internet.

There is nothing technically wrong with having two Subnets connected together on the same switch. But, it does show a lack of understanding of basic networking.

Typically you subnet your network to separate machines physically. Either via a different switch and network segment, or via vLANs. If all machines are connected to the same physical network then it is unpredictable which DHCP server will provide the IP address for each machine.

In either case, you have to have a gateway address (which is a router) connected to BOTH network subnets.

You have a dLink connected to 192.168.10.1 but nothing connected to the 192.168.20.x network. Your dLink (assuming it is a home router) is NOT going to do this.

You'll need to plug in a second router on 192.168.20.1 and have both routers connect back to your ISP or a 3rd router in some way.